# Eclipse ADB does not support USB 3

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

I cannot make Eclipse ADB debugging on SS (Super Speed) port aka USB 3.0
The device always shown Offline or Unknown.

Apparently because I stick the device cable to USB 3.0 port. After I switch to USB 2.0 port everything works perfectly.

Is that so? Anyone know the reason behind?

---

After several months passed. I tried again today. And now it works. I really don't know what caused that in previous case.

Comment: Hi, I'm facin the same problem... Have you found a solution for that ?

Comment: No, I just switched it back to ordinary USB 2.0 port to continue my work.